# jQuery parse ajax response data and get element id - value

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have a jQuery ajax get that will return an html text. From this one I need to extract the h3 element (with id='title') value: `THIS IS TITLE`.

Can I achieve this with jQuery?

```
<div class="content">
   <h3 id="title">THIS IS TITLE</h3>
   .....
</div>
```

and here is the call:

```
  $.ajax({
      url: url,
      type: 'GET',
      cache:false,
      success: function (data) { // data is the html text returned

       alert('The title is: ' + TITLE HERE);

      }
  });
```

Comment: Maybe using find I guess ?

Comment: `$(data).find('#title').text()`

Comment: Since Id is unique, you can use $('#title').text()

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use **find()** method to get the value like below,

```
$(data).find('#title').text()
```

An Example for how to use find is here [How to Use find()](http://jsfiddle.net/antoKing/A52NG/3/)

Answer (score 2):

Use RegExp:

```
text='<div class="content"><h3 id="title">THIS IS TITLE</h3>.....</div>';
console.log(text.match(/<h3 id="title">(.*?)<\/h3>/)[1]);// or alert:
alert('The title is: ' + text.match(/<h3 id="title">(.*?)<\/h3>/)[1]);
```